# Using question mark in CodeIgniter routing

Tags: php, regex, codeigniter, routes, wildcard

I need to change

```
http://mysite.com/profile?username=nick
```

to

```
http://mysite.com/user/nick
```

with CodeIgniter routing. I add the following line to `routes.php` but it doesn't work:

```
$route['user/(:any)'] = "profile?username=$1";
```

Here is the `.htaccess` file that I use:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
```

How can I solve this problem? Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

I mean URL structure changing. So after the routing it must *redirect*

```
http://mysite.com/user/nick
```

to

```
http://mysite.com/profile?username=nick
```

Answer (score 1):

Htaccess rule to handle the redirect:

```
RewriteRule user/([^/?]+) /profile?username=$1 [L,R=301]
```

Route.php change:

```
<?php
$route['profile'] = 'profile/index';
```

Profile controller:

```
<?php
class Profile extends CI_Controller {

    public function index()
    {
        $username = $this->input->get('username');
        // do lookup based on username
    }
}
```

**HOWEVER**: this sort of redirection only makes sense if you have a lot of cached links that don't make sense to change.  It sounds from your question that you might be confusing the concepts of routing and redirecting.

---

**EDIT**: To "route" (rather than "redirect"), here are the steps:

Htaccess rule to internally re-route requests:

```
RewriteRule /profile?username=([^&]*) index.php/user/$1 [L]
```

Route.php:

```
<?php
$route['user/(:any)'] = 'user/index/$1';
```

Controller:

```
<?php
class User extends CI_Controller {
    public function index($username)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

If that doesn't work, then, well, you're doing a terrible job explaining your problem :).

Comment: Using the word "redirect" when you mean "route" makes every answer exactly the opposite of what you want.  I'll edit it.

Answer (score 0):

The issue most likely is that the `?` is a special character in regular expression language meaning either 1 or 0. You will need to escape it for it to match, something like so should solve your issue:
`$route['user/(:any)'] = "profile\?username=$1";`

Answer (score 0):

Okay, you want to do it the other way around. Try:

```
RewriteRule user/([^/?]+) index.php/profile?username=$1 [L]
```

<sub>Sorry if this doesn't work, my Apache isn't cooperating.</sub>